# Live DVD and status DRDY

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, dvd

I am trying to install Linux on my pc as dualboot. On this PC, I am using windows since 2 years.

After booting with a live DVD of Kubuntu 15.04 (I also tried it afterwards with an USB-Stick and Linux Mint 15 DVD and Fedora 17 DVD), I get an error "/dev/sdc: No medium found" ... status { DRDY } (please have a look at the screenshot):

[image]

- As I said, Windows worked for 2 years now, on this pc
- I also tried too boot with an old (i dont know, maybe 5-6 years??) GParted Live CD an with this Live-Distri, I had no problem and I reached the Xfce gui.
- I tried my kubuntu dvd on my notebook, without any problems.

Any ideas, how to fix this problem, so that I can install linux on my pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out, that it has something to do with the sata3 ports. I justed switched the sata ports used for my ssd and t

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the reason is a non-generic SATA controller the HDD or SSD is connected to. I had to switch to a controller built in a chipset to get rid of the problem, thanks to the previous answer.

Comment: Suggestion: The part "...had to switch to a controller built in a chipset..." may require description by using a screenshot. At least I can't understand which part of hardware/software this answer is trying to describe.